# get Nil when calling for IBOutlet properties in function

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, iboutlet

i’m working in swift and i’m trying to use the .frames to check if 2 objects of type CGRect intersect.
i have my View Controller Class and a CircleClass, the CircleClass creates a circle that has gesture recognition so i can drag the circles that i create where i want to, now i want to add the option that if at the end of the drag the subview intersects my trashimageView (image view that will always be in the low-right corner of the view for all devices it's like a trashcan) it can delete the circle or subView.

the problem is that when i try to call trashImageView.frame in a function “deleteSubView” that i’ve created in the View Controller i get nil and my app crashes.

But if the IBOutlet is in the VC and my function is defined in my VC, also i can call the trashImageView.frame (CGRect Value) in the viewDidLoad and there is fine, but not in my function, why do i get nil for this value??

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var trashImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //here i can print the CGRect value just fine
    print("my imageView init: \(trashImageView.frame)")

}

func deleteSubView(subView: UIView){

    // Here i get nil from the trashImageView.frame

    if (subView.frame.intersects(trashImageView.frame)) {
        print("intersection")
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
}
```

i've checked that the Nil value is from the 'trashImageView.frame' and that the connection with the storyboard is good.

i call the function ‘delete subView’ from another class but should that matter? i don’t understand what is the error here, why do i get nil? help please.

Comment: Where are you calling `deleteSubview`?

Comment: "i call the function ‘delete subView’ from another class but should that matter?" - yes; how do you get the reference to the view controller you are calling it on. Chances are that it is just a new reference you are creating so none of the outlets have values. I believe I suggested to you a couple of days ago that your view controller needs to handle the dragging and intersection test, not the view.  The view's only job is to draw a circle

Comment: i call the 'deleteSubView' function in a class called 'CircleClass' who's job is to create a circle when tapping on screen and drag it  when the screen senses the PanGesture. 
 I have a switch in this Pan function that sais when the drag of a element ends, it calls the deleteSubView function.                                                                             
 So, the circle class should just do the drawing and leave the gesture recognition part in the View Controller? ain't another way?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `UIViewController` is declared and *instantiated* using storyboard my guess is that you are creating the view controller using it's no arg initializer, i.e.: `let controller = MyController()` if you must create an instance of the controller programmatically do so by obtaining a reference to the Storyboard that contains the controller, i.e like this:

> *NOTE*: Here I'm using "MyController" as the name of the class and the identifier that has been set in the storyboard.

```swift
func createMyController() -> MyController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyController")

    return controller as! MyController
}
```

I'd also add a guard for view load state in your `deleteSubview(:subView)` method, so something like this:

```swift
func deleteSubView(subView: UIView) {
    guard isViewLoaded else { return }

    // Here i get nil from the trashImageView.frame
    if (subView.frame.intersects(trashImageView.frame)) {
        print("intersection")
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: the function createMyController should i use it in the class where i want to create the instance of my ViewController? or in my ViewController? and once created should i call it's parameters as 'MyController.trashImageView.frame' so i don't get Nil?

Comment: It should be called by the class that needs the MyController instance, when using it at that point the iboutlets shouldn’t be nil